# Date function in sikuli

Tags: java, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I need to get the current date in sikuli script. 
I am using below code snippet in my script, in which DATE has been hardcoded and that need to change on daily basis to run the script daily.
I have tried to find in documentation, but couldn't find there.
CODE SNIPPET:

```
type(Key.TAB + "ABC" + Key.TAB + "06-17-2015" + Key.TAB + Key.TAB + Key.DOWN + Key.TAB + Key.TAB + Key.TAB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Pythons `time`, `datetime` does not work wel with Sikuli 
For example:

```
import time

now = time.strftime('%c')

# Date 
print ('Date: ' + time.strftime('%x'))
# Time 
print('Current time: ' + time.strftime('%X'))
#Current date and time.
print ('Current time %s' % now )
```

Change the `"06-17-2015"` by `time.strftime('%m-%d-%y')`.